# what's the difference between a shim repository and a repository?

Tags: shim, highlightjs

for instance, [this one](https://github.com/components/highlightjs) is a shim repository for highlightjs. I know a shim or a polyfill is always used to fit in low level broswers. But I am focus in chrome only, and when I change the shim highlightjs to to [normal one](https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js/), it results in a lot of error.

So I wonder what's the difference between a shim repository and a repository? can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 0):

The term "shim repository" has become somewhat popular for web programming components projects. Those repositories are "shims" in the sense that they created as a stand-in for those components and released in a standard format that meets the needs of 3rd-party projects and their package managers that incorporate these components.

Wikipedia [defines a shim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shim_(computing)) as follows

> In computer programming, a shim is a small library that transparently
>   intercepts API calls and changes the arguments passed, handles the
>   operation itself or redirects the operation elsewhere. Shims can be
>   used to support an old API in a newer environment, or a new API in an
>   older environment. Shims can also be used for running programs on
>   different software platforms than they were developed for.

That's pretty much it.